# Multiple file management in JQUERY application

Tags: jquery, document-ready, javascript-scope

How should Split JQUERY with multiple files or access variable inside one

file1.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var a='Ram';
});
```

file2.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   console.log(a);
});
```

Order of inclusion in html,
file1.js
file2.js

Its not working, I want to make it work, How do I go about.

Comment: Change file 1 to `var a='Ram';`

Comment: you mean to say remove jquery dom ready ?

Comment: Yes, as it's restricting the scope of the `a` variable. At the very least move the `a` definition *outside* of document.ready, as the only thing that needs to be inside there is code which accesses the DOM

Comment: Yes because you cannot rely on which line is executed first since they both run on load. You can even remove both unless a is needed in the DOM

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Golden words:" Put the code that only access dom inside dom ready"